# Searching an ArrayList for a string and returning another associated string

Tags: java, arraylist

```
private ArrayList<SocialMediaAccount> socialMediaAccounts;

public void addSocialMediaAccount(String userID, String websiteName, String websiteURL, int activityLevel) 
{
    SocialMediaAccount object = new SocialMediaAccount(userID, websiteName, websiteURL, activityLevel);
    socialMediaAccounts.add(object);
}
```

I have this `ArrayList` and I need to search for a particular websiteName and return the userID associated with the object. 
Getting confused a lot and would like some help on getting started with this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi refer to the comment I left on your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through the arraylist and check if the websiteName matches the websiteName that is stored in the list like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < socialMediaAccounts.size(); i++)
    if(socialMediaAccounts.get(i).getWebSiteName().equals(the_website_you_arelooking_for){
    return socialMediaAccounts.get(i).getUserId
    }
}
```

Comment: `if` needs an extra right paren, but overall premise seems sound.

Comment: Hi, the header code I have to use is      `public String getSocialMediaID(String websiteName)`

Comment: Hi no, I'm not too sure how to use that header with the code you provided or with Rahul's solution.

Comment: @FarazDurrani  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this method will solve your question. Hope you have getters inside your socialMediaAccount class.

```
public String getuserID(ArrayList<SocialMediaAccount> socialMediaAccounts,String websiteName){
 for(SocialMediaAccount s:socialMediaAccounts){  
    if( s.getWebsiteName().equalsIgnoreCase( websiteName)){
        return s.getUserID;
    } 
} 
return "no user found";
}
```

Comment: Rajith I think this answer is not correct. Because if the first condition fail, it will just return **no user found** and get out of the loop. don't you think?

Comment: @Faraz  you are correct.. I have modified the code.

Comment: `{}` at end of `if` is suspect; shouldn't it be just `{`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson my bad. I fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
//This method will return the userID associated with the given target websiteName.
//Insert it where you need it.
public String search(String targetWebsiteName){
    //loop through each account in your list.
    For(SocialMediaAccount acc: socialMediaAccounts){
      SocialMediaAccount tempObject = acc; 
       //check for websiteName
       if(tempObject.getWebsiteName().equals(targetWebsiteName)) return tempObject.getUserID();
    }
return null;
}


//Add these methods to your SocialMediaAccount class
class SocialMediaAccount{

       //Getters for object variables
       String getWebsiteName(){
            return websiteName;
       }

       String getUserID(){
           return userID;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of items in your list and you're doing a lot of searches, a `HashMap` using the the website name as the key will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think what you will want    

for (SocialMediaAccount socialMediaAccount: socialMediaAccounts) {
            if (socialMediaAccount.getwebsiteName() == your_website_search_name) {
                return socialMediaAccount.getId();
            }
        }
        return null;
```

Comment: `==` won't do it; you need to use `socialMediaAccount.getWebSiteName().equals(your_website_search_name)`